# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException with combinations Spring, Maven and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm new here and I hope so that I will find a solution for my problem. I have a exception org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException with save data in ManyToMany relationship. I use Spring framwork and  Maven.

This is my annotations for hibernate

```
//class Result
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "result_player", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "result_id", nullable = true) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "player_id",  nullable = true) })
private List<Player> players;

//class Player
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="players")
private List<Result> results;
```

Part for hibernate and jdbc settings in application-context.xml file

```
<!-- ORM, Hibernate, JDBC -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:cfg/properties/jdbc.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="mytable.scores.model" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
</property>
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${jdbc.dialect}" />
    <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />

    <entry key="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8" />
    <entry key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8" />
    <entry key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
</util:map>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

When I saved Result with List where is new Players, everything is fine and save , in table result_player saved ids . But if I then take that player , change , put in Resultplayers  List and tray to save , then I get this error org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException detached entity passed to persist: Player

I read many answers for this error but in combination of Spring and Maven with Hibernate annonations I don't know, do I need to settings something else or I need to call some method (persist() )? When to call pesist?before or after storage object?

Thanks in advance for any help....

Answer (score 1):

I think that for you is first important understand somethings on **Entity Life Cycle**.

[image]

In your first case

> When I saved Result with List where is new Players, everything is fine and save

I think that  you are creating a new object and then you are able to use persist, in the second case when you got the exception in my opinion your object doesn't managed yet, and then when you try to use you get the exception. Try to use merge intead persist to solve the problem

Comment: thanks for pic. and answer . I thought that Spring all that done because I put annotations "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" but obviously I have to invite persist() methods. I must to read the documentation because I never use this. I was hoping to spring with annotations all that done :))

Comment: The exception says that you are trying to persist an detached object, this is all. Spring has nothing to do

Comment: I started reading the documentation. Thank you very much for the advice, I hope to quickly solve the problem ...

Comment: I've tried a lot of solutions. Now when I try to do the persist() method, appear to me these errors ... org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [ctx/application-context.xml]  , and this .. Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  ... probably need some adjustments for persistence but I do not know what else to adjust ????

Comment: @zexco2 Can you share the full stack trace with us?

Comment: I do not know why I can not put the code in response to my question, I always get this error  "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon." and I used all same like at the first question ... ???